# Use 'find' to find and delete large files of a certain type

Tags: linux, find, rm, redhat-enterprise-linux

I am trying to `find` and `rm -rf` large files in RHEL, but what I would expect from this command that would give me purely the file directories, feeding them into `rm -rf`, it is not removing them. My FU might be off, so please review this line, I thought it would work.

```
find /tmp -type f -size +50000k -exec ls -lh {} \; | awk '{ print $9 }' | rm -rf
```

Comment: What about `find /tmp -type f -size +50000k -delete` ?

Comment: That's exactly what worked, I was going to post an answer, but I'm taking care of something else at the moment. You can answer with that. That works.

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs – why you shouldn't parse the output of ls

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `find /tmp -type f -size +50000k -delete` instead, which is clearer, simpler and more efficient.